# Search log file for string with bash script

Tags: string, bash, grep

I just started learning PHP. I'm following [phpacademy's](http://phpacademy.org/) tutorials which I would recommend to anyone. Anyways, I'm using XAMPP to test out my scripts. I'm trying to write a bash script that will start XAMPP and then open firefox to the localhost page if it finds a specific string, "XAMPP for Linux started.", that has been redirected from the terminal to the file xampp.log. I'm having a problem searching the file. I keep getting a:

```
grep: for: No such file or directory
```

I know the file exists, I think my syntax is wrong. This is what I've got so far:

```
loaded=$false
string="XAMPP for Linux started."

echo "Starting Xampp..."

sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start 2>&1 > ~/Documents/xampp.log

sleep 15

if grep -q $string ~/Documents/xampp.log; then

    $loaded=$true
    echo -e "\nXampp successfully started!"

fi

if [$loaded -eq $true]; then

    echo -e "Opening localhost..."
    firefox "http://localhost/"

else

    echo -e "\nXampp failed to start."
    echo -e "\nHere's what went wrong:\n"
    cat ~/Documents/xampp.log

fi
```

Comment: standard trick for debugging, `set -vx` or change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x` and check that everything is expanded as exxpected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In shell scripts you shouldn't write `$variable`, since that will do *word expansion* on the variable's value. In your case, it results in four words.

Always use quotes around the variables, like this:

```
grep -e "$string" file...
```

The `-e` is necessary when the string *might* start with a dash, and the quotes around the string keep it as *one* word.

By the way: when you write shell programs, the first line should be `set -eu`. This enables **e**rror checking and checks for **u**ndefined variables, which will be useful in your case. For more details, read the Bash manual.

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for a string you should put wihtin quotes.
Try `"$string"` instead of `$string`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems:

- quote variables if you want to pass them as a simple argument `"$string"`
- there is no `$true` and `$false`
- bash does variable expansion, it substitutes variable names with their values before executing the command. `$loaded=$true` should be `loaded=true.`
- you need spaces and usually quotes in the if: `if [$loaded -eq $true]` `if [ "$loaded" -eq true ]`. in this case the variable is set so it won't cause problems but in general don't rely on that.

Comment: Isn't `test foo -eq bar` meant to do a *numerical* comparison?